# SuperReader and SuperUser accounts as managed accounts with password change schedule?

Tags: sharepoint-server, password, managed-account, object-cache

I was wondering if it comes to any complications when I set the SuperReader and SuperUser account as a managed account with a password change schedule?

I found this thread: [How does SharePoint 2010 uses the SuperReader/SuperUser accounts?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109809/how-does-sharepoint-2010-uses-the-superreader-superuser-accounts) which describes the basic functionality. But I don't get the point why it is not recommend to set these accounts as managed accounts?

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to: there is no actual process that logs on using these accounts. In fact: you don't even need to know the password of these accounts, you just need to know the user name, that is enough.

Comment: In addition to this answer, you can freely change the password at any time without making any changes in SharePoint. There will be no impact from a password change.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such requirement to register these accounts as managed, Because these accounts are not running any services in SharePoint rather these are normal domain accounts with higher permission level. These are treated as normal user accounts.

You can manage object cache accounts under managed account, there is no restriction on it. It will not hurt the SharePoint, but i can see it will help u to managing these accounts.

I get your point, may be as per company policy you have to change password after x days, if SharePoint can do automatically without interrupting any thing than why not. Yes, you can do this.